# Adding value to existing cookie value using JS and Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, cookies

I have an existing cookie called "watchlist" and would like to have an additional value added to this cookie.

I am currently using PHP Laravel framework but am using JS to handle cookie operations.

Currently, no errors occur but nothing happens.

CookieOperation.js:

```
function autoAddWatchlist(movie_id){
    var value=JSON.parse($.cookie("watchlist"))
    value.push(movie_id);
    $.cookie("watchlist",JSON.stringify(value));
}
```

HMTL Code , within Laravel blade page:

```
<script src="{{asset('js/CookieOperation.js')}}"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="autoAddWatchlist(373571)" >Add</button>
```

I would like to add the value to existing cookie.

Comment: some important questions: 
is your function called? (Alert test)
Does the push work if your coockie is empty at the moment?
Do you need to set an expire time?
What does your variable look like after stringify? And most importantly, what do you make sure that didn't happen? Debugger? What is your expectation?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I've completed an alert test and , yes, this works. How do I do the check on alerting the variable after stringify? 
The expectation is that the number is added to the cookie at the end

Comment: try a "console.log(value)" after the stringify and post the output

Answer (score 0):

Answer - thank you @MThiele.

```
function autoAddWatchlist(movie_id){
    //alert("Function Alert");
    var temps = Cookies.get('watchList');
    var value=JSON.parse(temps);
    value.push(movie_id);
    //console.log(value);
    //alert(value);
    Cookies.set('watchList', JSON.stringify(value), { expires: 7000 });
    getWatchList();
    //alert(Cookies.get('watchList'));
    location.reload();


}
```